# ubuntu 19.04 dock adaptive mode

Tags: lubuntu

04 ubuntu to 19.04.
And my ADAPTIVE dock mode vanished, tried

> gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode 'ADAPTIVE'

but it shows me

> The provided value is outside of the valid range

Do I have any way to get ADAPTIVE mode back?

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive transparency mode [has been removed](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/commit/8ccc7d2d55e1b425be605ff3d29052f5a43994ec) from Dash to Dock because of the upstream changes in Gnome itself: the top bar [has been reverted](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/commit/9cfb51c106abd1f96012bf39f3d329cf060035cf) to opaque mode.

So yes, that's it: unfortunately, **Dynamic panel transparency extension does not affect Dash to Dock anymore** and I did not find a proper solution for now. I'm no one to judge, but if you ask me, I think Gnome developers have made quite a few questionable decisions in the past (hello, tray icons).